A trick needed!
If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are positive matrices such that $q= \left| \frac{tr[A B C]}{\sqrt{tr[AB]}} \right|^2$. Then one can use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $|tr[x^* y]|^2  \le tr[x^* x] tr[y^* y]$ (where $*$ is conjugate transpose) to write
$$q= \left| \frac{tr[A B C]}{\sqrt{tr[AB]}} \right|^2 = \left| tr\left[\frac{\sqrt{A} \sqrt{B} }{\sqrt{tr[AB]}} \sqrt{B} C \sqrt{A} \right] \right|^2 \le tr\left[ \frac{AB}{tr[AB]} \right] tr[BCAC] = tr[BCAC]$$
But now if we have $q$ defined with respect to a new metric (see theorem 3 of this article) as $q_w = \left| \frac{tr[A B C w]}{\sqrt{tr[AB w]}} \right|^2$. Then it seems hard to get rid of the denominator to obtain something like $q_w \le tr[\cdots w]$. Is there any way of expressing some upper value of $q_w$ devoid of the denominator?

Try harder to be descriptive/specific in your title, please.

Shouldn't it be $tr[BC^2A]$ instead of $tr[BCA]$?

@user1551, my apologies. I have corrected the expression now.
